# Confused with nested lambda types in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Just trying to see the types of some lambda expressions like this one:

```
:t \x -> (\y -> x y)
\x -> (\y -> x y) :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t2
```

shouldn't the type here be `t1->(t2->t1->t2)` ?

Similarly

```
:t \x -> (\y -> (\k -> y (x k)))
\x -> (\y -> (\k -> y (x k)))
  :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t2 -> t3) -> t1 -> t3
```

Shouldn't the type be `t1->(t2->(t3->t2))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> :t \x -> (\y -> x y)
> \x -> (\y -> x y) :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t2
> ```
>
> shouldn't the type here be t1->(t2->t1->t2) ?

No, `t1->(t2->t1->t2)` is the same as `t1->t2->t1->t2` which is the type of a three-arguments function (of type `t1`, `t2`, and `t1`) returning `t2`. However, there are only two lambdas, for the two arguments `x` and `y`.

The right type is instead

```
typeOfX -> (typeofY -> typeOfResult)
\x ->      (\y ->      x y)
```

(By the way, none of the parentheses above are needed.)

What is `typeOfResult`? Is is the type of `x y`, so it is the return type for `x` which must be a function.

In order for the code to type check, we must then have that `typeOfX` is a function type, say `a -> b`. In such case we can see that `typeOfResult = b`. Further, in `x y` we pass `y` to `x`, and this can type check only if `typeOfY = a`.

So,

```
typeOfX  -> typeofY -> typeOfResult
=
(a -> b) -> a       -> b
```

The compiler used names `t1` and `t2`, but this is the same type.

Parentheses here matter, since we must remember that `x` is a function `a -> b`.
Without parentheses we would get a three-argument function, as explained above.

You can try to apply the same reasoning to the second example. Start from 
`typeOfX -> typeofY -> typeOfK -> TypeOfResult`, and slowly discover what these types actually are.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `x` in `\x -> \y -> x y` is `t1 -> t2`, and it's the first argument.
As the outermost lambda, it gets applied first, followed by `y`

You could've written it as `\x y -> x y` which is just function application in the natural order.